# Is there a way in javascript to retrieve random objects from an array and assign them randomly to a divny clicking a button?

Tags: javascript, object, frontend

I want to get a random quote from an array of objects with quotes with their respective author name by clicking a button. So far I am in a roadblock and can't seem to understand how to proceed. Below is the markup
Get a random code with the click of a               button!

---

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

John Doe

GET A NEW QUOTE!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
const allQuotes = [

{   
qid: 1,
quote: "Quote 1",
auth: "ABC DEF"
},

{       
qid: 2,
quote: "Quote 2",
auth: "XYZ ABC"
},

{       
qid: 3,
quote: "Quote 3",
auth: "XYZ ABC"
},

{       
qid: 4,
quote: "Quote 4",
auth: "XYZ ABC"
},

{       
qid: 5,
quote: "Quote 5",
auth: "XYZ ABC"
},

{   
qid: 6,
quote: "Quote 6",
auth: "XYZ ABC"
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const allQuotes = [{qid: 1, quote: "Quote 1", auth: "ABC DEF"}, {qid: 2, quote: "Quote 2", auth: "XYZ ABC"}, {
  qid: 3,
  quote: "Quote 3",
  auth: "XYZ ABC"
}, {qid: 4, quote: "Quote 4", auth: "XYZ ABC"}, {qid: 5, quote: "Quote 5", auth: "XYZ ABC"}, {
  qid: 6,
  quote: "Quote 6",
  auth: "XYZ ABC"
}];

const randomObj = (arr = []) => {
  const num = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
  return arr[num]
};
console.log(randomObj(allQuotes));
```